# Android display Timeout Message in Web Service when connection or read timeout while internet connected

Tags: android, web-services, connection-timeout

> Hi I need to display the message "Data not Received" on connection or read Timeout.
>
> I implement this using java.net.SocketTimeoutException but can't get message if there is no data received while internet connected.
>
> I get only help through the internet connected or not.
>
> But actually I want to get it when the internet is connected.

## Internet Connectivity Test Code

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Activity activity) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

## Code

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        httpConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(String.valueOf(values));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream iStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
        }
    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Network Error : No Data Received.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : ", e.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: remove these lines and try again. httpConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

Comment: You can use Volley . Volley can easily handle this kind of issue .

Comment: @ZahidulIslam yes better to use Volley

Comment: Then how do it identify that when will timeout and catch exception ???

Comment: The exception is not being caught ok. But what you are getting when there is a read or connection time out?? App crashes?? If yes then please paste the logcat.

Comment: It caugh by Exception but not in SocketTimeoutException and returns
E/Error :: java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: `UnknownHostException` means the URL you are passing is not correct. Try loading that url to your browser. @Rushvi

Comment: It Works good but using this code. But i need to show timeout exception if the connection timeout or read timeout..

Answer (score 0):

For displaying Toast:

```
catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Network Error : No Data Received.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

}
catch (Exception e) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: How do this code work if exception doesn't caught by java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: I test this code using only enables wifi without internet connection so there for connection doesnt get within timeout so it should be show "No Data Received" message... but didn't get it.

Comment: There is one other catch clause below this one. The exception will be caught by it.Try printing the same in below catch clause. I think SocketTimeOut is not being raised.

Comment: Exception caught by another exception block and throws the unknown host error there..

Comment: That means it is not timeout exception. There is something wrong with your **URL**. check by loading it to browser.